# How do sync 100 or more set of user to firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am trying to add authentication to my Angular 2 application ( Could be anything, I am using angular 2) but I wanna give access to a limited people lets say (100 or more, I have datastructure ready) using Firebase. They will not sign up, their email id will be their username and fullname will be password. If I wanna create all of their user authentication at once, how do I do that (without adding the manually)? And when the user logged in successfully I need to show their details. How to linked the details with logged in user?
I am beginner, not sure where to start with. I did tried the Firebase docs, but couldn't make anything out of it.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really quite a broad topic, much more than can reasonably answered here. But to pre-create a bunch of email/password users, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: Hey, Thanks for getting back to me. Appreciate it. Lets say I did manage to create the users. But how do I link them to their details? I am not talking about just fullname or profile pic, but I wanna link other details too.

Comment: A common pattern for that is to have a database collection of extended profile information at `/users` which is keyed by UUID, ie a user with UUID 'abc123' would have a node at `/users/abc123` and any extra data you need can be stored there.